# Mosaico Toolbar Editor - how do we get file upload?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

On the latest and greatest of Civi and Mosaico, I installed this extension: https://github.com/ginkgostreet/com.ginkgostreet.mosaicotoolbarconfig

However, what plugin and toolbar control would get us access to the file upload dialog in the classic Civimail editor? (KCFinder)

For some background, we can utilize the Mosaico gallery, but we'd like access to our actual file structures so we can utilize all the work we put into the original Civimail